# Why is Nebraska shot in black & white?

Tags: analysis, film-techniques, nebraska

Why is the movie Nebraska shot in black & white? What theme does it resemble in this movie?

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebraska_%28film%29):

> The film was shot in black and white because Payne said he wanted to
> produce an "iconic, archetypal look". According to cinematographer
> Phedon Papamichael, the choice was to use "the poetic power of the
> black and white in combination with these landscapes and of course the
> landscapes are playing a huge role in this story". The choice of
> black and white was made against distributor Paramount Vantage's
> wishes. The film was shot with Arri Alexa digital cameras and
> Panavision C-Series anamorphic lenses.
>
> Payne has claimed that a
> color version was created in an effort to satisfy distributor
> Paramount Vantage's concerns, but that he hopes no one ever sees
> it.

From a [different interview](http://www.vulture.com/2013/05/cannes-alexander-payne-nebraska-black-and-white.html):

> At the press conference afterward, you’d better believe that the first
> question to Payne is the one that wary marketing executives must have
> asked him, too: “*Why black and white?*”
>
> “I wasn’t expecting that
> question at all,” Payne replied dryly.
>
> But the director of Election
> and Sideways is no dummy, and if he didn’t already have an answer
> prepared for a question he’s bound to be asked until Nebraska’s
> November release date — and beyond — he still managed an erudite
> response on the fly. “It just seemed like the right thing to do for
> this film,” he said. “*It’s such a beautiful form, and it’s really left
> our cinema because of commercial, not artistic, reasons; it never left
> fine-art photography. This modest, austere story seemed to lend itself
> to being made in black and white, a visual style perhaps as austere as
> the lives of its people.*”

And one [final interview](http://parade.condenast.com/265496/scottneumyer/nebraska-director-alexander-payne-talks-bruce-dern-and-the-iconic-look-of-black-and-white/):

> *You’ve said that there is a color version that you made for Paramount,
> but you “hope no one ever sees it.” I couldn’t agree more with that.
> Black and white fits this film perfectly. What is it about the iconic
> black and white image that color just can’t deliver?*
>
> I think in an age
> when the recording of visual information digitally is making the image
> more and more faithful to reality—how it really looks in real life and
> even realer to an extent—people lose themselves more in a recorded
> image than they do amidst real life. So in an age where the image on
> television with HDTV, 4K, and all these other formats of digital
> images are so clear, we don’t want that from art. We want art to
> transform our perception of reality. We want to see the recognizable
> in a new way, which actually makes you look at it. And, with some
> luck, it also gives it some beauty or vividness, and I think black and
> white is a perfectly good medium to do that. Let’s not forget as well
> that our great cinematic heritage is largely in black and white. It’s
> nothing new and it never left fine art photography.

Answer (score 1):

The use of Arri Alexa and panavision lenses looks like it was not supported by a lot of lighting to give the film a cinematic style - as a result black and white takes away a lot of the distractions such as noise and varying color temperatures generated by a digital image capture in multiple locations and available light.

The choice I am sure is also creative and considered - but it does allow for a cheaper and faster shooting schedule - it also reduces costs in post production as the only areas that have to be manipulated in image are contrast and exposure once saturation is reduced to nothing.